# How does the search work differently for Chinese words and English words?

Tags: search

In the search settings page, the search key length is "3" by default. It makes sense for English words. For Chinese words, to get search result, I have to input 4 words like "欢迎光临". Actually, we'd like to search only 2 words(eg."欢迎", I think it is common for Chinese to search). That means I have to set the search key length to "1". Is it possible to set the key length separately for English and Chinese? Or is it possible to take one Chinese word as key length “2”？